# Have a problem when I trying to convert an associative array to a JSON form php and pass to Python

Tags: python, php, json, dictionary, associative-array

My purpose is create a simple associative array and encode it to JSON this in PHP, after that I want to pass to a python script and this information decode into a dictionary, so for that I created this simple test:

This is my PHP script:

```
// DICCIONARIO DE PRUEBA
$dicSample = [
    "dogBreed" => "Golden Retriever",
    "name" => "Mia"
];

// Codificar json primero para evaluarlo
$jsonCon = json_encode($dicSample);

//Ejecutar script
$output = shell_exec("python prueba.py " . escapeshellarg($jsonCon));

echo $output;
echo "<pre>";
echo $jsonCon;
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

This is the Python Script, to be more descriptive I wrote the control structure  to read the errors if the JSON don't pass properly:

```
import sys, json 

try:
    consultaSQL = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
    print(consultaSQL)
except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
    print("Error al decodificar el JSON:", str(e))
```

When I execute the PHP script in the browser I get this output:

```
Error al decodificar el JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
{"dogBreed":"Golden Retriever","name":"Mia"}
```

As you can see all the process return me an error message and the JSON encoded from PHP, the associative array don't have special characters or something ar first view, at this point I don't have any idea of what 's happening here.

I really appreciate the help that you could give me.

I'd a complex associative array before but I wanted to try something simpler with that example but I get the same result.

Once accomplished is there a way to pass that JSON information to a python script that uses python-docx-templates and render a word document?

Comment: The issue you're encountering is due to the way command line arguments are passed and parsed. When you pass a JSON string as a command line argument, it can get misinterpreted due to spaces, special characters, etc. A better approach would be to pass the JSON data through standard input (stdin) to the Python script. This way, you can avoid potential issues with command line argument parsing.

Answer (score 0):

With this approach, you're echoing the JSON string and piping it to the Python script, which then reads from stdin. This method is more reliable for passing complex data between scripts.

**PHP Script**:

```php
<?php

// DICCIONARIO DE PRUEBA
$dicSample = [
    "dogBreed" => "Golden Retriever",
    "name" => "Mia"
];

// Codificar json primero para evaluarlo
$jsonCon = json_encode($dicSample);

//Ejecutar script
$command = "echo " . escapeshellarg($jsonCon) . " | python prueba.py";
$output = shell_exec($command);

echo $output;
echo "<pre>";
echo $jsonCon;
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

**Python Script**:

```py
import sys, json 

try:
    consultaSQL = json.load(sys.stdin)
    print(consultaSQL)
except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
    print("Error al decodificar el JSON:", str(e))
```

Finally, you can pass the JSON encoded associative array to a Python script that uses `python-docx-template` to render a Word document.

Make sure you have the `python-docx-template` library installed (`pip install docxtpl`).

For this example, the Python script reads the JSON data from stdin, loads a Word template using `DocxTemplate`, renders the template with the data, and then saves the rendered document. Adjust the paths (`path_to_template.docx` and `path_to_output.docx`) as needed.

Here's how you can do it:

**PHP Script**:

```php
<?php

// Associative array
$dicSample = [
    "dogBreed" => "Golden Retriever",
    "name" => "Mia"
];

// Encode to JSON
$jsonCon = json_encode($dicSample);

// Execute script
$command = "echo " . escapeshellarg($jsonCon) . " | python prueba.py";
$output = shell_exec($command);

echo $output;

?>
```

**Python Script (prueba.py)**:

```py
import sys, json
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

try:
    data = json.load(sys.stdin)

    # Load the docx template
    doc = DocxTemplate("path_to_template.docx")

    # Render the template with the data
    doc.render(data)

    # Save the rendered document
    doc.save("path_to_output.docx")

    print("Document rendered successfully!")

except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
    print("Error decoding the JSON:", str(e))
```

This approach should work well for your use case.

Comment: Is super accurate this solution, my next step is pass that JSON information to a python script that uses python-docx-templates and render a word document,  so, the way to pass the JSON encoded associative arrays could be works like this?:

// Assoxiative array
$dicSample = [
    "dogBreed" => "Golden Retriever",
    "name" => "Mia"
];

// Codificar JSON
$jsonCon = json_encode($dicSample);

//Execute script
$command = escapeshellarg($jsonCon) . " | python prueba.py";

$output = shell_exec($command);

Comment: Epic, liked the second approach and works so good, really thank you so much, is true that stdin is reliable and can pass more complex associative arrays.